# How to see during swimming for short sighted people

Tags: swimming

I am learning to swim right now so I can go to water parks when summer rolls around. However, I am very short sighted. Under water I use prescription goggles to see, but when I get out of the pool or if I go to the water park, get out of the ride, how can I see?

The problem is, at water parks, I can't store my glasses anywhere (I could store it in the lockers but then I wouldn't be able to see while I am waiting in line) and during the ride. I don't want to wear goggles when I am not in the ride.

What are some solutions for shortsighted people for swimming and going to the water parks

Comment: I have this same problem, and I have been looking for a solution for the longest time! Just resorted to wear my glasses while swimming until I finally invested in a pair of Prescription swim goggles.

Comment: How much being short sighted affects your swimming in open water? Normally, you don't enjoy sightseeing while open water swimming, all you need is to be aware where the shore is to keep your swimming direction about where you want to swim...

Answer (score 1):

You can add a strap to your actual glasses. Combine that with a cleaning cloth which is useful when you leave the water. (Eg : [Oakley Performance Strap Kit](https://www.oakleysi.com/en-us/product/W0OO90602C))

Or you can also buy a pair of prescription swimming glasses. You can either found those with predefined dioptres online or from your optician.

Comment: Indeed, I use off-the-shelf optical goggles And am very near sighted. They work in and our of the water just fine. Slightly more expensive than regular goggles, but only a few dollars more.